# react with timer rerenders all x seconds

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react 16.12.0 with react.component.

I have a timer function which runs every 6 seconds. Every 6 seconds I am asking the server for information:

```
timer(): void {

this.setState({time: new Date()});

this.sendFunction({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'getDataFromServerAfterTimeX',
    data: {
        "timestamp": this.state.lastUpdate,
    }
}, "getDataFromServerWithChangesAfter");
}
```

The problem now is that react is re-rendering every 6 seconds because of the `setState` call in the timer function.

The timer value is never anywhere shown to the user. It is only used to save the current time and when the server sends some information to the the client the value lastUpdate will be updated to the `value-timer`.

How can I prevent react to re-render every 6 seconds?

I tried with `shouldComponentUpdate` but this function isn't helpful, because I have to check every state-variable if it has changed. When any state variable has changed react should render, otherwise only the value `timer` has changed so return false. But I have around 50 state variables. I cannot check every 6 seconds if one value has changed or not.

Can anybody give me an advice. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

then don't use it as state variable ,instead make it a local variable. closures can help. can you show code?